# 64 Bit Java and 64 Bit Access

Tags: java, database, netbeans, 32bit-64bit

I am using Netbeans 32 Bit with 32 Bit Java installed on a Windows 7 64 Bit Machine.

I am Also using Office 2010 64 Bit.

My Problem is that every time I try and connect a Access database to my project it comes up with the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

java.lang.NullPointerException

This is my code:

```
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String SourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=" 
                + new File("Argos.accdb").getAbsolutePath() + ";";

        Argos = DriverManager.getConnection(SourceURL, "admin","");
```

I have tried using 64 bit Java within Netbeans but the same error occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Is the driver jar in your classpath?

Comment: Im not sure which part you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.But i have 64 bit win 8 and 32bit office im using jdk 32bit and in net beans it works but when i use executable jar